# Need some informations about requests and wrike api

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to query write api with something like that
[https://www.wrike.com/api/v4/ids?ids=[18813418,18813416]&type=ApiV2Task](https://www.wrike.com/api/v4/ids?ids=%5B18813418,18813416%5D&type=ApiV2Task)
I've tried different way to add an array in my `request.get()` params and never start to work.

```
def getIds():
    url = 'ids'
    print(Idlist)
    querystring = {}
    querystring['ids'] = [152899268]
    querystring['type'] = 'ApiV2Folder'
    jsondata = WrikeResponse(url, querystring)
    return jsondata['data']
```

```
def WrikeResponse(url, querystring):
    wrikeurl = Config.get('WRIKE', 'url') + url
    auth_token = Config.get('WRIKE', 'api_token_do')
    payload = ""
    hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}
    jsondata = ''
    response = requests.get(url=wrikeurl,
                            headers=hed,
                            data=payload,
                            params=querystring)
    print(response.url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        jsondata = response.json()
    else:
        jsondata = response.status_code
    return jsondata
```

The error always says that ids in integer, not array.

Comment: please [fix all the typos](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63902744/edit) in your code.

Comment: `GET` parameters should be passed in the URL

Comment: @Tibebes.M Wich typos are bad ?

Comment: @JammyDodger already tryied and everything is ok when i don't put an array in parameters

Comment: @DavidOrel They are edited now (except for those inside your code). see the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63902744/revisions)

Comment: @Tibebes.M Ok i've seen thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `querystring`, use an Integer instead of a List for the `ids` key.

Change from:

```
    querystring['ids'] = [152899268]
```

to:

```
    querystring['ids'] = 152899268
```

Comment: I've already try this with no succes , also i can have multiples ids to search

Comment: What if you try to submit a String? e.g. `querystring['ids'] = '[18813418,18813416]'`

Comment: i have an error saying that i must submit an array not a string

Comment: add the original full error to the post otherwise we don't know what the error actually says